# Prove $\frac{n-1}{n}+\frac{n-1}{n}\frac{n-3}{n-2}+ \frac{n-1}{n}\frac{n-3}{n-2}\frac{n-5}{n-4} + ... = \frac{n-1}{3}$ without induction

Tags: algebra-precalculus, summation, proof-writing, induction, fractions

I found this identity using Maple. Is there a (simple) way to prove it without using induction? Using induction, the proof is quite easy.

Prove for odd $n$ that
$$\sum_{k=1}^{(n+1)/2}\prod_{j=0}^{k-1} \left(\frac{n-2j-1}{n-2j}\right)=\frac{n-1}{n}+\frac{n-1}{n}\frac{n-3}{n-2}+ \frac{n-1}{n}\frac{n-3}{n-2}\frac{n-5}{n-4} + ... = \frac{n-1}{3}$$

Comment: As soon as you can define $\sum_{k=1}^n$ without recursion

Comment: @HagenvonEitzen I changed the limit. Was that the problem?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

We need to prove that
 $$\frac{n-1}{n}+\frac{n-1}{n}\frac{n-3}{n-2}+ \frac{n-1}{n}\frac{n-3}{n-2}\frac{n-5}{n-4} + ... = \frac{n-1}{3}$$ or
$$1+\frac{n-3}{n-2}+ \frac{n-3}{n-2}\frac{n-5}{n-4} + ... = \frac{n}{3}$$ or
$$\frac{n-3}{n-2}+ \frac{n-3}{n-2}\frac{n-5}{n-4} + ... = \frac{n-3}{3}$$ or
$$1+\frac{n-5}{n-4} +\frac{n-5}{n-4}\frac{n-7}{n-6} ... = \frac{n-2}{3}$$ or
$$.$$
$$.$$ 
$$.$$
$$1+\frac{2}{3}=\frac{5}{3}.$$
Done!

Comment: Plus 1 for the nice presentation.  But I don't think you've avoided induction.

Comment: @B. Goddard  Yes you are right of course. In  each problem, where there are "...", we actually use an induction. I think it means to prove our identity without cases: 1. base; 2. assuming; 3. proof. If we want to use the idea of the telescopic sum then we also need to use induction, but I think it's just delirium to make it with  previous cases 1;2 and3.